# Cannot talk to atmega328p over AVRisp mkII

Tags: linux, microcontroller, avr, atmega, avrdude

I have similar issue as here([AVRISPmkII connection status: Unknown status 0x00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313269/avrispmkii-connection-status-unknown-status-0x00)) but different setup and changing bitcklock didn't help.
The current setup is  atmega328p with external oscillator 16MHz connected to ISP interface of avrisp mkII programmer but whatever I do It keeps on showing the same output all the time:

```
mike@asus:~/wireless-temp-sens/tests$ sudo avrdude -p atmega328p -P usb -c avrispv2 -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xd9:m -U efuse:w:0xfe:m -v

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 17:07:18
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/mike/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : avrispv2
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found AVRISP mkII, serno: 000200209719
         AVR Part                      : ATmega328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500V2
         Description     : Atmel AVR ISP V2
         Programmer Model: AVRISP mkII
         Hardware Version: 1
         Firmware Version Master : 1.23
         Vtarget         : 4.9 V
         SCK period      : 2053.39 us

avrdude: stk500v2_command(): command failed
avrdude: stk500v2_program_enable(): bad AVRISPmkII connection status: Unknown status 0x00
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you powering your circuit? AVRs aren't like PICs (which are powered by the programmer during ICSP) - they need external power for programming. Or, at least, that programmer doesn't provide power.

Comment: Yes, external power supply 5V is connected.

Comment: Also, green led on the programmer is on. Does it mean my wiring is ok? I am a bit confused with MISO and MOSI. Should the MISO of the programmer be connected to MOSI of the chip? However, I tried both ways and it doesn't work.

Comment: The connections should be straight through, not crossed (MOSI to MOSI, MISO to MISO, etc).

Comment: Do you have a resonator or oscillator set up?

Comment: I have 16MHz crystal and two 22 pF capacitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved! Don't remember what was the reason exactly. I guess clock crystal didn't have proper connections on a breadboard. So, I would say:

1. Check your wiring
2. Check your wiring
3. Check your wiring

Comment: Finally my problem was the 6 wire ribbon cable.